# SharePoint 2010: Set character limit of news webpart without SP Designer?

Tags: web-part

The SharePoint 2010 news/announcement webpart cuts off messages after 250 characters. I would like to set a higher character limit.

All solutions I have found so far involve SharePoint Designer which is not allowed in my company.

Is there a way to modify the character limit without using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in option to set this limit.

One possibility would be to export the webpart and edit the parameters in the exported webpart defition file, but the standard listview webparts (what the announcement webpart is) cannot be exported. :(

An other possibility is to add the announcements list to the page (as a list view webpart) and edit the view. Select the columns to show (title, body, date), set the filter (expires > [today]) and set the style to 'newsletter') This will come close to the built in webpart.

Comment: I had already suspected there is no built-in option...

Export/import is not allowed (at least the import). I had already tried the list view idea, but as you say it is only close to the built-in webpart.

I am currently thinking about using the announcement list + XSL for a nice representation.